# Accents in inline javascript

Tags: javascript, unicode, utf-8

I know that for javascript alerts accented characters should be written in unicode hex (for example š is \u0161).

But what if the javascript function which contains the alert is inlined inside a html document, that has a UTF-8 encoding? Should I still write the accented characters in unicode hex?

Example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ro">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">

</head><body>

<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload=error_alert();function error_alert(){alert('A apărut o eroare!')}
</script>

</body></html>
```

Is it safe to write the character "ă" just like that, or should I use \u0103 ? Remember that meta charset is already defined as UTF-8.

Comment: I might use `\uxxxx` just to be safe, but I believe it'd work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you could still use [escape sequences in JavaScript strings](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-escapes), even if they’re inline in the HTML.

> Is it safe to write the character "ă" just like that, or should I use \u0103 ? Remember that meta charset is already defined as UTF-8.

It depends. If you’re sure that the HTML document includes `<meta charset=utf-8>` and will always do so, or if the server sends the `Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8` HTTP header and you’re sure it will always do so, then by all means, use the raw symbols without escaping them.

There’s a problem, though — these things are not always under your control. Visitors might be behind a proxy that strips or mangles HTTP headers or modifies the encoding of the HTML response.

In any case, the safest thing to do is to use escape sequences for any non-ASCII characters, as that way the entire source code consists of ASCII characters only. (You could use [HTML character references](http://mths.be/he) for the HTML parts of the document, and [CSS escape sequences](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/css-escapes) for CSS.)